# How to stop FullSimplify from returning Root objects

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I have several expressions in a series, such as

```
1/4 (-(1/4) + Sqrt[5]/4 + I Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8]) (-1 - Sqrt[5] + 2 Sqrt[7/2 + (5 Sqrt[5])/2])
```

If I run `FullSimplify` over it, it returns a `Root` object,

```
Root[1 + #1 + 3 #1^2 + 5 #1^3 + 6 #1^4 + 5 #1^5 + 7 #1^6 + 2 #1^7 + #1^8 &, 8]
```

which is rather useless for further computation. Of course, using `ToRadicals` (which seems to be the general answer I've found for this situation) does not work with a degree 8 polynomial. The full expressions are very cumbersome, and using only `Simplify` is not enough. So I need to run `FullSimplify` over them.

The only solutions I've found so far, as I said, rely either on `ToRadicals`, or in not using `FullSimplify` at all.

Does anybody know how to stop `FullSimplify` from returning these objects, while still being able to do the simplifications?

Thanks!

Comment: sol=FullSimplify[ Root[…]/. Root-> root]/. root-> Root ?

Answer (score 3):

Root-expressions are very useful. It is worth reading the documentation about it. Often, doing computations with Root-expressions is simpler and more general than with Radicals.

Having said that, it might be that you are looking for something like this:

```
FullSimplify[1/4 (-(1/4)+Sqrt[5]/4+I Sqrt[5/8+Sqrt[5]/8]) (-1-Sqrt[5]+2 Sqrt[7/2+(5 Sqrt[5])/2]),
  ComplexityFunction -> (1000 Count[#, Root[__], All] + LeafCount[#] &)]

(*  -(1/16) (-1+Sqrt[5]+I Sqrt[2 (5+Sqrt[5])]) (1+Sqrt[5]-Sqrt[14+10 Sqrt[5]]) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this myself just a moment ago.  The trick is to use a user-defined Complexity function:

```
expression = x^3 - 2*x^2 - 6*x + 5 
f[e] = 100 Count[e, _Root, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
Simplify@Solve[expression == 0, x]
FullSimplify@Solve[expression == 0, x]
FullSimplify[Solve[expression == 0, x], ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

---

$$\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{11}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{39}\right)}+\frac{2\ 11^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{39}\right)}}+2\right)\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{1}{6} i \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{11}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{39}\right)}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{11^{2/3} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{39}\right)}}\right\},\left\{x\to -\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\frac{11}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{39}\right)}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{11^{2/3} i \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{39}\right)}}\right\}\right\}$$

---

$$\left\{\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3-2 \text{$\#$1}^2-6 \text{$\#$1}+5\&,3\right]\right\},\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3-2 \text{$\#$1}^2-6 \text{$\#$1}+5\&,1\right]\right\},\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^3-2 \text{$\#$1}^2-6 \text{$\#$1}+5\&,2\right]\right\}\right\}$$

---

$$\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{11}{2} \left(-1+3 i \sqrt{39}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{11}{2} \left(-1-3 i \sqrt{39}\right)}+2\right)\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{1}{6} \left((-2)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{-11+33 i \sqrt{39}}-2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{11+33 i \sqrt{39}}+4\right)\right\},\left\{x\to -\frac{1}{3} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{11}{2}} \sqrt[3]{-1+3 i \sqrt{39}}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2 (-11)^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{-\frac{27}{2}+\frac{81 i \sqrt{39}}{2}}}\right\}\right\}$$

This is adapted from the basic example in the [ComplexityFunction documentation page.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = 1/4 (-(1/4) + Sqrt[5]/4 + I Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8]) (-1 - Sqrt[5] + 
     2 Sqrt[7/2 + (5 Sqrt[5])/2]);

expr2 = expr // Simplify
```

[image]

You can in this case -- and may with the full expressions -- get a simpler form if you express in terms of the `GoldenRatio`

```
(expr3 = (expr /. Sqrt[5] -> 2 Inactive[GoldenRatio] - 1) // Simplify // 
    Activate) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
expr == expr2 == expr3 // Simplify
```

> True